# PHPUnit is Working With Command Line, but not with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, phpunit

Whenever I run a test file from eclipse it works and display result as:

```
.                                                                1/1 (100%)

Time: 371 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

But If I run the same test from the Eclipse Oxygen, I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of PHPUnitLogger::addFailure(Test $test, AssertionFailedError $e, $time): void must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener::addFailure(PHPUnit\Framework\Test $test, PHPUnit\Framework\AssertionFailedError $e, float $time): void in /tmp/phpunit_printer/PHPUnitLogger.php(415) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

I downloaded phpunit-7.1.phar, and installed it globally by making it executable and moving it to /usr/local/bin and for Eclipse, I have downloaed in the Download directory and without making it executable I added it into my Eclipse Project as an External Phar but it is not working and giving the above error.

Can someone help me fixing the issue?

By the way, I am a NetBeanse User, but NetBeans is not supporting PHP7.1 that's why moving to Eclipse.

**UPDATE**

Here is my test file:

```
<?php
namespace tests\Unit\;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSimple() {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure eclipse use the same version of phpunit as you use on command line?

Comment: I can only make sure that the same phpunit phar I used for the global installation and to add as an external phar in my eclipse project. So, this must be same.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with PHPUnit 7.5.14 and didn't find a solution.

Since I wanted to test my application running with PHP 7.1, I decided to try PHPUnit 6 and it worked at once. So PHPUnit 6.5.14 did the trick for me.

It seems Eclipse is not compatible with PHPUnit 7. My Eclipse Version is 2018-12 (4.10.0) with PDT 6.2. After switching to PHPUnit 6 other problems (that I managed to find workarounds for) were gone too. For example the generated class code overrides TestCase::__construct without calling the parent constructor. It seems to be a problem with PHPUnit 7, not so with 6.

I didn't find a compatibility chart of Eclipse PDT to support my thesis.